# How to implement items on sale in a webshop

Tags: database-design

I am trying to build a webshop and I am having a bit of a discussion with myself about how to implement items on sale.

Is it better to have a ItemsOnSale-table containing references to items on sale, or a OnSale-field in the Items-table.

I have convinced myself that the first solution is more correct, in that listing items on sales requires less of traversing the Items-tree, and also because if information about the sale changes, it does not have to change the Items-table just the ItemsOnSale which seems more "orthogonal".

However, I am no expert so what do you guys think?

**Edit:**

```
[products]
Id
Name
Price

[items_on_sale]
ProductId
NewPrice

[orders]
ProductId
UserId
```

This raises the question of how to select products such that the price from items_on_sale overrides the products price.

Comment: I think it greatly depends on the **logic of your store** and the items. Would you have a detail statistic of the items transactions: who bought, when, quantity, etc. Which other values are **relevant** on the sale **itself**? My recommendation if that you should use a content manager (joomla, drupal, etc.). Nevertheless, if you are doing the code for learning a language or the logic of the store, that`s another history.

Comment: Yes I would like to have detailed statistics, but that's in another table, maybe Orders or something like that.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add more information about the **relations of the DB**. With that, we could get an idea of the concept of the store in general and give you a more specific answer. In particular: fields of the item table and the relation with that table.

Comment: Now edited. This is how I imagined it (simplified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to implement a store my entities would initially exist like so:

> **Products**
>   id, name, ...
>
> **Prices**
>   id, price, date, is_sale, ...
>
> **Orders**
>   id, product_id, customer_id, date, ...

This way, you are able to keep a record of the prices throughout the products history. If the new price (or discount) is anything other than a standard price drop, flat `is_sale` that way your view can reflect that. This will also enable you to be able to do a was/now if the change happened recently.

Comment: something I've also seen used on a pricing table is also date ranges for when the pricing is valid (or goes into effect)

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Let me think about it for a while. Thanks!